# Python print to stderr in generator

Tags: python, fuse

Building a python fuse fs, in my readdir generator the first line of code is a print statement. This never appeared on my console. I modified it to a print to stderr as i thought it was a buffering issue. Still no output.

I added a manual flush to the next line - still nothing.

I added a time.sleep(3) to the next line, the prog does indeed sleep.

```
def readdir(self, path, offset):
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Text'
    sys.stderr.flush()
    time.sleep(3)
```

I then go on to populate the directory with other code (yield fuse.Direntry)
I do get output and can do an ls in the terminal to see the contents of my mounted fuse directory, but I want to know why the print command doesn't work in this one generator.

Update

For those that are struggling :

```
def readdir(self, path, offset):
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Text'
    sys.stderr.flush()
    for o in os.listdir( "." + path ):
        yield fuse.Direntry(o)
```

Is the code. It generates a file list and I can move around it. That is fine.
The problem is I never see 'Text' appear, not in STDOUT, STDERR, anywhere.

I was simply asking why this happens only in this generator. I can put print elsewhere in the fuse code and get output very well.

Comment: @delnan I'm sorry, I do not understand your comment. I do mention that I go on to use yield further down the code if that is your comment.

Comment: @delnan Please re-read his post, he does in fact say that there is a `yield` in code he doesn't show.

Comment: This is the code (I can't get it to work in this comment) ` def readdir(self, path, offset):
  print >> sys.stderr, 'Text'
  sys.stderr.flush()
  for o in os.listdir( "." + path ):
   yield fuse.Direntry(o)`

Comment: @agf: I only see "I then go on to populate the directory with other code (yield fuse.Direntry) I do get output". I may be misreading, but to me that means "I add a `yield` to this code, and suddenly it works like it should". Which seems perfectly sensible - the library requires a generator and stuff doesn't work when you don't give it a generator.

Comment: @delnan - No. I have a yield in the code, as explained. As clearly explained, I can 'ls' and 'cd' into my fuse mounted directory and see the files, but the MAIN issue, the print statements produce no output anywhere, ever, even though they are clearly being executed.

Comment: Okay, nevermind then and excuse the misunderstanding.

Comment: Have you tried running the code in a debugger?  It's entirely possible that somewhere in the code that you're passing the Generator to they've temporarily reassigned `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`.  If you open a write handle to another file somewhere, and push your print statements to it, do they show up?

Comment: Yes, I have a logger running anyway, and all the log messages show up. As I'm fairly new to python (but not coding) I was wondering if there was a lang specific reason for this behaviour. As it is fuse, you could be right that there is some redirection going on. I do have the debugger setup through macports, but not for my currently selected python.

Comment: Gddc was correct. It appears the fuse code redirects stdin, out, err itself and is not specific to the python bindings or language. [ref : http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=1199067861.3249.315.camel%40ipcus&forum_name=fuse-devel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FUSE code runs under the control of FUSE library, so you can't be sure that `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are the ones in your terminal session.
It's quite possible that the `readdir` generator is called with alternate `std*` streams.

Since you say that other parts of your FUSE code `print` without any issues, you might want to prefix all `print` statements with a debugging log message (the value of `sys.stdout.isatty()` or even the `repr(sys.stdout)` could be handy) to help you understand what is going on.

Comment: I already implemented a logger from the logging class that allows me to know what's going on.